# В чем ошибка аjax удаления комментария?

Tags: php, ajax

Изучаю ajax и решил переделать на своем тестовом сайте удаление комментариев. Собственно данный код удаляет комментарий только после перезагрузки страницы. Подскажите, где моя ошибка?
html:

```
 <? foreach ($comments as $comment) : ?>
            <div class="comments">
                <div class="row comtext">

                    <div class="comname">
                        <?=$comment['name'];?>
                        <br>
                        <?=formatTime($comment['date']);?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="comtent">
                        <?=$comment['text'];?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="delete">
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light"  id="<?=$comment['id']?>">Удалить</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <? endforeach;?>
```

JS:

```
 $(".comments .btn").on('click', function(){
    var commentId = this.id;
    var $currentComment = $(this).parents('.сomments');

    $.post("../delete.php", {id : commentId}, function( serverResponse ){
        if( serverResponse === 'ok' ) {
            alert('hi');
            $currentComment.remote();
        }
    })
})
```

PHP:

```
if($_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] === 'POST') {
  if( is_numeric($_POST['id']) ) {
    $commentId = (int)$_POST['id'];
    $sqlDel = 'DELETE FROM comments WHERE id = ' . $commentId;
    $result = $db->query($sqlDel);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> код удаляет комментарий только после перезагрузки страницы

Он так и должен делать потому, что Вы в JS коде ничего не обновляете на странице.

По идее должно быть не:

```
$currentComment.remote();
```

а:

```
$currentComment.remove();
```

Если уж на то пошло.

Comment: Да и так и так пробовал. Все равно только после обновления удаляется.